# Angular 5: Run function after time when change data in input

Tags: angular, angular5

How to detect changes in input and run function after time 1500.
debounceTime not working coreclty
My code:

```
this.filterInput
    .valueChanges
    .debounceTime(1500) <- not working corectly
    .subscribe(text => {
        //function to run
    })
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` inside the subscribe

```
this.filterInput
    .valueChanges
    .subscribe(text => {
        setTimeout(
           ()=> {
              console.log("Executing after 1500ms");
           }, 1500
        )
    })
```